# How to handle an update to a major version

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

I have an application live on PlayStore (and AppStore), with version number as 1.5.1, and VersionCode 151.

I'm starting to work on major 2.0 version and can't find information how handle it. I mean, if I publish to alpha channel VersionCode 200, all goes ok. But if next week I need to deploy a bug fix for the previous version, I'll need to deploy a VersionCode 152 to Beta channel, but Play Store will chime because is a minor VersionCode that the last Alpha channel.

Basically I'm asking what is the state of the art to handle major versions on PlayStore (if compatible with App Store, good).

I read some where that some people handle multiple Package Names (different applications). If this is the case, when is time to finally deploy 2.0, should rename the package to the same as production and deploy as beta on his channel ? This mean that at this point (upload 2.0 to beta on main application) I'll lost capacity to release any update to previous version ?

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question and your actual question seem to differ.

If all you are asking is how to handle major version, then there are various ways of doing it. But in summary, it's all about employing policies on when to update the major version and then go on to automate the process or do it manually.

At the end of the day, essentially, one needs to update `versionName`. And `versionCode` incrementally.

However, if I look at the premise of your question you seem to be indicating a different scenario. Let me try and answer based on what I gather from the premise of your question.

If you are updating your app, from version 1.5.x to 2.0.x, and increment the versionCode to 200, there are two scenarios:

1. You publish the 2.0.x app to the same bunch of users that had 1.5.x. And in that scenario, if you want to fix anything on 1.5.x, then you will fix it on 2.0.x and deploy with versionCode, say 201. So, all users will get your fix.
2. You publish the 2.0.x app to a different stream of users, say, users who meet certain criteria of `minSdkVersion`. Then what happens is you will be left with two versions of your app in the Play Store. The two apps can be differentiated by min SDK version. You will need to maintain two separate branches in your code base. And Play Store will not complain if you update the two apps separately with different version code updates. As in, it will not complain if you update an apk which is, say, 1.5.1 152, and another apk which is 2.0.0 201.

As a best practice, it is quite widely followed to bump the version code by a value of 50, when you are jumping the major version and also fragmenting your target audience.

Comment: I'll to try explain better. 1.5 is actually a live app, and want to start 2.0 on alpha channel. So if I want to deploy 1.5.1 to beta channel I need to put VersionCode to 201 and at that point Alpha channel will be disabled because there is a new version on Beta, and Alpha users will get the 'old version'.

My question is how keep a workflow where I can keep both version without disrupt users testing the new version and keep releasing bug fixing for the old one.